# Unbound variable during url printing in bash/shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, openstack

I have 2 variables that I want to use to derive a 3rd variable:

```
export REGION_NAME=phx

export phx_url=https://www.google.com
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
echo "$((${REGION_NAME}_url))"
```

And I get the following error:

```
-sh: https://www.google.com: syntax error in expression (error token is "://www.google.com")
```

All I am trying to do is to derive an environment variable from an other one but it does not work simple like that. I think it has to be escaped and could not find anything online.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$((...))` is arithmetic expansion. You didn't mean that. Try normal variable expansion (with indirection) instead.

```
REGION_NAME=phx

phx_url=https://www.google.com

R_VAR=${REGION_NAME}_url    

echo "${!R_VAR}"
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is using `eval` like:

```
var="phx"
eval "${var}_url='some'"
echo $phx_url   #prints "some"
```

But, I not recommending this (because the `eval` could be pretty dangerous).

Instead of use `associative arrays` (aka hash variable), like:

```
declare -A urls

var="phx"
urls[$var]="some2"
echo "${urls[phx]}" #prints "some2"
```

Comment: Way to bury the lede. (Maybe next time put the "right way" first?) Anyway, +1.